# Java and setting a variable equal to an array

Tags: java, arrays, input

How do you set a variable equal to an array in Java.  For example I have a class for input and a class for calculations which hold arrays.  when I accept the user input from the input class how do I pass that variable into the array of my calculation class?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code of what you already have?

Comment: Yeah.. Its tough to decipher what you're telling

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Code sample below:

```
public MyClass method(String ...arg);
```

You can call this method as :

```
method("test1", "test2", "test3");   // with arbitrary number of values.
```

Or as

```
String[] test = something;
method(test);
```

Comment: double sample [] = { priceone, pricetwo,pricethree  }

Ok for exampl lets say I have array sample and I want to pass into array sample the variables of priceone pricetwo and pricethree. The variables are from an input class.

Comment: @water - You could simply do sample[0] = priceone; etc. That's if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have strict requirements to use arrays, you should probably be using a Collection, like a List.

For example, if you're trying to manage an array of ints, you could instead do:

```
List<int> intList = new ArrayList<int>();
```

Then, if you really need the data in the form of an array, you can do:

```
intList.toArray();
```

Which would return an array holding the integer values in your list. Lists are easier to read and use.